Спрятать блок при выборе в select значений больше определенного
есть код:
<div class="yearperiod" style="float: left; width: 300px; height: 50px;">Отчётный период:
<select style=" width: 60px; height: 30px; padding: 3px 2px; margin-bottom:5px;" name="year" id="year99" class="js-year-locker">
<?php
foreach ($yearArray as $year1) {
$selected1 = ($year1 == $god_0) ? 'selected' : '';
echo '<option '.$selected1.' value="'.$year1.'">'.$year1.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</div>

в нем года с 2018 по 2025
необходимо чтобы при выборе значений больше 2023 скрывался
<div class="kbk2024"> </div>

заранее огромное спасибо!

всем спасибо, помогли в другом месте
$('#year99').change(function() {
if ($(this).val() > 2023) {
$('.kbk2024').hide();
} else {
$('.kbk2024').show();
}
});

